# Cannot start docker image - "cannot find module json-server"

Tags: javascript, docker

I have a docker-compose attempting to start this image [vimagick/json-server](https://hub.docker.com/r/vimagick/json-server), however I have added something slightly more than the default case shown in the docs, opting to pass a server file of my own.

```
json-server:
    image: vimagick/json-server
    command: --host 0.0.0.0 -w db.json -r routes.json -m server.js
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./support/json-server/db.json:/data/db.json
      - ./support/json-server/routes.json:/data/routes.json
      - ./support/json-server/server.js:/data/server.js
    restart: always
```

When I start the docker image, the log simply states:

```
 Loading server.js
{ Error: Cannot find module 'json-server'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/data/server.js:1:20)
```

I have checked that I have json-server installed locally, but for some reason cannot get this to work.

Any ideas would be welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

Make a folder called `./json-server` and place the following files in it:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:lts-slim

RUN npm install -g json-server

WORKDIR /data
VOLUME /data

EXPOSE 3000
ADD entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD []
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

args="$@"

args="$@ --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3000"

file=/data/db.json
if [ -f $file ]; then
    echo "Found $file"
    args="$args --watch $file"
fi

echo "json-server $args"

json-server $args
```

**./json/[routes.json, db.json]**

Edit above if you want to pass or watch other files etc.

Then in `docker-compose.json`, something like this

```
json-server:
   build: ./json-server
   volumes:
     - ./json-server/json/:/data
   ports:
     - 3000:3000
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem here seems the fact that you are passing:

```
 command: --host 0.0.0.0 -w db.json -r routes.json -m server.js
```

this will run inside the container so installing json-server locally doesn't change anything , if you want you can create and image and start from  vimagick/json-server
a dockerfile would be like :

```
FROM vimagick/json-server
 ...
```

and install json-server if needed